# Python interpolation between two large data arrays

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have two data sets for different years (2015 and 2024) and need to interpolate for 2019. The issue is the size of these data sets; after importing them and trimming off the unnecessary columns of data, each 1D array for each year is still over 4M points long. I need to create a new array with the interpolated points for 2019, but so far what I've attempted seems to take a really long time (a test of 200 data points took about 25 seconds). How can I speed this up?

```
#import data already done, trimming off unnecessary (Location1,Location2) columns.
JT_2015 = np.delete(data_2015,[0,1],1)
JT_2024 = np.delete(data_2024,[0,1],1)

#creating empty array to append interpolated data in to.
JT_2019 = np.array([])

#separate Location1,Location2 set to attach interpolated data to later
nodeSets = np.delete(data_2024,[2],1)

#flattening to 1D arrays
JT_2015 = np.ravel(JT_2015)
JT_2024 = np.ravel(JT_2024)

#loop to interpolate all data points
for i in range(0,len(JT_2015)):
    a = JT_2015[i]
    b = JT_2024[i]
    calc = np.interp(2019,[2015,2024],[a,b])
    JT_2019 = np.append(JT_2019,calc)
```

Answer (score 0):

When you only have two points (2015 and 2024) you are stuck with [linear interpolation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_interpolation#Linear_interpolation_between_two_known_points). So you might as well do it directly:

`JT_2019 = JT_2015 * ((2024-2019)/(2024-2015)) + JT_2024 * ((2019-2015)/(2024-2015))`